# How to retrieve last uploaded artifact name inside a GitHub Action Tasks?

Tags: maven, github, github-actions, artifactory

I am currently working on automating a Java Build and Deployment task where I am using GitHub Actions to perform the Build and Deployment. I am working on snapshots build and the artifact is pushed to JFrog Package Manager and the artifact name looks like `jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT.war` but when it gets pushed to my JFrog Snapshot Repository the same artifact seems to be uploaded with some timestamp as suffix like `jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC1-20220715.124710-5.war`.

How to ensure that I deploy the last recent snapshot artifacts on my target servers? I need some way to retrieve the last recent artifact name from JFrog Package Manager.

**Note:**

- I know that we can use `upload-artifact` action to Archive the Artifact and can be used at later jobs with `download-artifact` action to perform the Deployment.

  ```
  name: Archive Build Artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
  ```
- But the Artifact size is of around 180 MB, so archiving the artifact of every build seems like not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

JFrog CLI offers extended support for complex download patterns. I think, following should help you -

First setup JFrog CLI in Github Action, check [this link](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-jfrog-cli) for installation.
Once CLI is configured to be used, you use following command to always download the latest snapshot.

```
jfrog rt dl --flat --limit=1 --sort-by=created --sort-order=desc --url=<ARTIFACTORY_URL> --user=<ARTIFACTORY_USER> --password=<ARTIFACTORY_PW> "<RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ARTIFACTORY_REPO>/jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC1-*.war"
```

You can further tune the command according to your need. Check [this link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) to understand more.

Also yes 180MB is big to cache in CI build.

Comment: There is an issue with this approach.. For example, the relative path my look like "<RELATIVE_PATH_TO_ARTIFACTORY_REPO>/jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC1-SNAPSHOT/jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC1-*.war" tomorrow we may move to jd-bulk-messenger-1.18.0-RC2-SNAPSHOT/*.war so how to handle this?

Comment: Checkout Virtual Repositories concept in Artifactory. This might solve your fixed repo requirement.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Virtual+Repositories